# If $f_n \to f$ in measure then there exists a subsequence s.t $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

If $f_n \to f$ in measure then there exists a subsequence s.t $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost uniformly.

I have proven that there is a subsequence such that the convergence is pointwise a.e. I am not sure what to modify in the proof to make it work.

My proof:

Pick a subsequence such that $\mu(\{x: |f_{n_k}-f|>\frac{1}{2^k}\}=A_k)<\frac{1}{2^k}$. Then by Borell-Cantelli $\mu (\limsup A_k)=0$. Now $f_{n_k}(x)\not \to f(x)$ $\implies$ $x \in \limsup A_k$, thus $f_{n_k}(x) \to f(x)$ a.e. Not sure how to make is almost uniformly.

Comment: Maybe Egorov theorem helps you. I dont know because I do not know in what space you are working. If you are in a nice space then Egorov tells you that if you have a sequence that converges a.e to some function then there exists a compact set $K$ such that $m(E\backslash K)< \epsilon$, and this is almost uniformly convergence. If this does not help you, maybe reviewing the proof of Egorov is a good idea

Comment: @HFKy I am not to assume it is finite measure. If it is finite then almost uniformly is equivalent to pointwise and the problem is easy.

Comment: Maybe something like: Considering $f_{n_k}$ as you say. Given $\epsilon >0$ the definition of convergence in measure show me that there exist $k_0$ such that $\mu( \{x:|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})<1 \ \forall k \geq k_0$. Hence try applying Egorov to the set $A = \{x:|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}$. This set has finite measure so no problem. For $A^c$ there is no problem too, because there $|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon \ \forall x$.